# JODA daylightsaving conversion

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

In one of my projects, I have to convert UTC DateTime to user specific Date and Time. I am using xml to get time offset and daylight saving parameters.

for example offset="GMT+2" dst="true"

if this is the case, then I have to convert the utc DateTime to GMT+2 considering daylight saving.

I read many blog posts and articles but didnt fully understand how to do this time and date conversion. Can somebody please show me an example using JODA DateTime or anything similar in java.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DateTime` instance in any given `DateTimeZone` you can convert it to another time zone with just `dateTime.toDateTime(otherTimeZone)`.

Comment: String timeZoneId = "GMT-10:00"; 

DateTime temp = oldDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId));

So this will automatically convert my oldDateTime which is in UTC to GMT-10 as per day light saving? 
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi Matt, yes I did, didnt work for some unkonwn reasons. So i used TimeZone instead to get offset value. thanks for all the help!